What is „Media Checker filesystem.video“ reported by „Sleep Aid“?
I installed the "Sleep Aid" app to analyze problems with my Mac not going to sleep mode well. It looks like a "Media Checker" process called "filesystem.video" is causing long insomnias. Also, keypad input, but I thought that could possibly related to the media checker. Does anyone know what this Media checker is?

UPDATE 17.05.24:
I monitored last night again with clam shell closed, but connected to Power and it really seems to be the media checker. I should also check "Remote Buddy", but I think the root is the media checker. Which gets clear in the second screenshot, where this caused longer insomnia than remote buddy.


Could the trackpad have an issue or be dirty?

Please tell us the model of laptop and version of macOS. Trackpads can go bad, as I found out today while proctoring an exam at my school.

I have a MacBook Pro 2018, with Intel Chip and Sonoma installed. The trackpad looks pretty clean.

Wonder why the trackpad shows up in the report then.

„Sleep Aid“ is a commercial product, what did their support team offer in regard to this process?

no, there is no media server running on my Mac, only on my NAS.

I got feedback from the developer:
"Media Checker" is one of Apple's "BlackBox" systems that they don't publish any details on, same goes for their "Neural Engine". We simply don't know what Apple is doing with those systems, I've had their "Neural Engine" wake my computer up in the middle of the night and burn the battery down for over 9 hours. If you want to stop these, the best way is to unselect "Wake for Maintenance" in the "Sleep Settings" page of Sleep Aid.

I have exactly the same problem: my M1 pro never goes into sleep mode (I can feel it, because after the night, it's lukewarm and not totally cold). So I installed the software and, ditto, I have “long insomnia”... Very often with the “Media Checker” but also the “Performance Reporter”. The OS is up to date... I've closed all my Adobe applications, I turn off my secondary screen, and I go to the menu and click on “sleep”... I don't understand. In fact, the processor is active all the time, which (I think) is not very good.
[](ht

Wake for Maintenance
So I fixed all my issues with deactivating "Wake for Maintenance" and "Smart Power Nap" in Sleep Aid.
This solution was found thanks to Sleep Aid's developer, who said:

"Media Checker" is one of Apple's "BlackBox" systems that they don't publish any details on, same goes for their "Neural Engine". We simply don't know what Apple is doing with those systems, I've had their "Neural Engine" wake my computer up in the middle of the night and burn the battery down for over 9 hours. If you want to stop these, the best way is to unselect "Wake for Maintenance" in the "Sleep Settings" page of Sleep Aid.

